# Coverting between JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have two questions.

1) Are these two same?

```
    {
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "abc",
         "id": "9998544"
      },
      {
         "name": "pqr",
         "id": "6524"
      },
      {
         "name": "xyz",
         "id": "11693"
      }
     ]
   }
```

and

```
    [
          {
             "name": "abc",
             "id": "9998544"
          },
          {
             "name": "pqr",
             "id": "6524"
          },
          {
             "name": "xyz",
             "id": "11693"
          }
   ]
```

2) Starting with the second one, Which is the easiest way of converting it into first one?

Comment: No. They are not the same as is fairly obvious in that the upper one starts with an object literal having the property data holding the array the lower one starts with. That should also answer your question on how to convert the lower to the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're different. The former is an object and the latter is an array. To convert the latter into the former, use `json_encode(array('data' => json_decode($str)))`.